# What characters invokes alt+enter for an excel cell (xlsx file format)? (wrap_text does NOT work)

Tags: python, excel, pdf, xlsx, xlsxwriter

`wrap_text` option that xlsxwriter provides does not work in my case since I need to convert the excel files into pdf format and for some reason pdf does not read text_wrap.

My code looks something like this:

```
string = text+'\n'+text2
ws.cell(row_place,col_place).alignment = Alignment(wrap_text = True)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out the way to do it. You can initiate the cell size before doing text_wrap, as that makes the size of the cell fixed when converting the excel page to an image.

```
rd = ws.row_dimensions[row_index]
rd.height = 22
ws.cell(row_index,col_index).alignment = Alignment(wrap_text = True)
workbook.save(filename)
```